# MongoDB wildcard in the key of a query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, wildcard

Is it possible to wildcard the key in a query? For instance, given the following record, I'd like to do a `.find({'a.*': 4})`

This was discussed here https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-267 but it looks like it's not been resolved.

```js
{
  'a': {
    'b': [1, 2],
    'c': [3, 4]
  }
}
```

Comment: i have the same issue with mongo.  i have many documents like this: { one: { two: { more:data }, too: { more:data } } }
once you're one level deep into the document tree, each node at the second level is a container for documents with consistent structure.  so i would like to be able to search like this: find({'one.*.some.data':5})

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As asked, this is not possible. The server issue you linked to is still under *"issues we're not sure of"*.

MongoDB has some intelligence surrounding the use of arrays, and I think that's part of the complexity surrounding such a feature.

Take the following query `db.foo.find({ 'a.b' : 4 } )`. This query will match the following documents.

```
{ a: { b: 4 } }
{ a: [ { b: 4 } ] }
```

So what does "wildcard" do here? `db.foo.find( { a.* : 4 } )` Does it match the first document? What about the second?

Moreover, what does this mean semantically? As you've described, the query is effectively *"find documents where any field in that document has a value of 4"*. That's a little unusual.

Is there a specific semantic that you're trying to achieve? Maybe a change in the document structure will get you the query you want.

Comment: thanks, that clarifies. More specifically, what I'm looking to do is wildcard just the specific node in the branch, i.e. any proper subfield of a. I'm not clear on how a.* says 'find where any field'. Isn't it 'find documents that have a top-level field 'a' with a subfield that matches 4'?

Comment: I think the confusion here is around "subfield". When I write `{a:{b:4,c:2}}`, I am saying that the value `a` is a JSON object. That JSON object has two keys `b` and `c`. The value of those keys are 4 & 2 respectively. When you are asking for `a.*`, you're effectively asking for syntax that loops through all of the keys in that JSON object. Your're not asking to *"loop through an array"*, you're asking to *"loop through an object's properties"*. That's a little unusual, which is why I'm asking for a specific use case here.

Comment: @gates: I have a use case.
myDocInMongo = {'someUnknownKey':{propToCheck:true}, 'someKnownKey':true};
Now, I want to find this document using the selector {someKnownKey:{$exists:true}} but i also want to make sure that none of the other keys have an object with the property propToCheck. So, like the following:
{'*.propToCheck':{$exists:false}, {someKnownKey:{$exists:true}}}

Answer (score 6):

Starting from MongoDB v3.4+, you can use [`$objectToArray`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) to convert `a` into an array of k-v tuples for querying.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "a": {
        "$objectToArray": "$a"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "a.v": 4
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      // cosmetics to revert back to original structure
      "a": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$a"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Cq3zkj0JvNQ) for your reference.

Answer (score 4):

I've came across this question because I faced the same issue. The accepted answer provider here does explains why this is not supported but not really solves the issue itself.

I've ended up with a solution that makes the wildcard usage purposed here redundant and share here just in case someone will find this post some day

**Why I wanted to use wildcards in my MongoDB queries?**
In my case, I needed this "feature" in order to be able to find a match inside a dictionary (just as the question's code demonstrates).

**What's the alternatives?**
Use a reversed map (very similar to how DNS works) and simply use it. So, in our case we can use something similar to this:

```
{
  "a": {
    "map": {
      "b": [1, 2, 3],
      "c": [3, 4]
    },
    "reverse-map": {
      "1": [ "b" ],
      "2": [ "b" ],
      "3": [ "b", "c" ],
      "4": [ "c" ]
    }
  }
}
```

I know, it takes more memory and insert / update operations should validate this set is always symmetric and yet - it solves the problem. Now, instead of making an imaginary query like

```
db.foo.find( { a.map.* : 4 } )
```

I can make an actual query

```
db.foo.find( { a.reverse-map.4 : {$exists: true} } )
```

Which will return all items that have a specific value (in our example `4`)

I know - this approach takes more memory and you need to manage indexes properly if you want to gain good performance (read the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/#use-a-sparse-index-to-improve--exists-performance)) and still - it's good for my use-case. Hope this helps someone else someday as well