# Fetch documents with condition on "array of objects" field in MongoDB with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, php-mongodb

I saw other similar questions to query array fields but most of them were for pure Mongo and I couldn't translate the solutions to PHP's driver 'find()'.

I also found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561147/mongodb-php-query-search-in-array?rq=1) but I couldn't use it to solve my problem.

The [PHP driver's documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/v1.7/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-find/) wasn't helpful as well, there's a single example for find() but the fields are not arrays like mine.

The field causing me trouble is "Sentenca", it's an array which contains "Situacao" and "Prob". Like the following:

```
"Sentenca": [{
        "Situacao": "nc",
        "Prob": 0.96
        }]
```

[image]

"Sentenca" always contains only one index [0] with these two fields.

I need to query all documents where "Situacao" is NOT "nc". All I know is that I should use the operar $nin but I have no idea how to do that using find().

The furthest I got is this (and this query isn't doing what I need):

```
$result = $collection->find( [ "Sentenca"=>["Situacao"=>['$nin'=>["nc"]]]] );
```

**EDIT:** I managed to make a query applying the $nin conditions for "Situacao" but for some reason this query returns nothing. If I try to echo the entries I get the error:

```
Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\LogicException: Cursors cannot yield multiple iterators
```

Comment: Query returns nothing because you don't have `nc` in your data? Is it so? It returns when you add prob because 0.96 matches the sample you added.

Comment: Not sure if that's what you said. But I have multiple occurrences of nc. Maybe it's a semantics issue and has to do with the second pair of brackets but

$result = $collection->find( [ "Sentenca"=>["Situacao"=>"nc"] ] );

Returns nothing and it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone on MongoDB forum solved the issue. You can use '.' to access an array element, then use $nin => 'nc'.

```
$result = $collection->find([

    "Sentenca.0.Situacao" => [
        '$nin' => ["nc"]
    ]
    
]);
```