# Any way to update all keys within a key in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection where every document has the following structure:

```
{
  a: {
       foo: [1, 2, 3],
       bar: [4, 5, 6],
     }
}
```

Is there any way to update both all the keys inside `a` together? i.e. say I want to set both `foo` and `bar` to `[]` without doing `$set: {'a.foo': [], 'a.bar': []}` but doing something like `$set: {'a.*': []`

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot use wildcard operators to select a field name.

So you will have to know the name of the field before you can update it.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179871/mongodb-wildcard-in-the-key-of-a-query) for more clarification.