# REGEX Searching in pymongo

Tags: python, regex, mongodb, pymongo

I am attempting to create a search in pymongo using REGEX. After the match, I want the data to be appended to a list in the module. I thought that I had everything set, but no matter what I set for the REGEX it returns 0 results. The code is below:

```
REGEX = '.*\.com'

def myModule(self, data)
    #after importing everything and setting up the collection function in the DB I call the following:
    cursor = collection.find({'multiple.layers.of.data' : REGEX})
    data = []
    for x in cursor:
        matches.append(x)
    return matches
```

This is but one module of three I am using to filter through a huge amount of json files that have been stored in a mongodb. However, no matter how many times I change this formatting such as /.*.com/ to declare in the operation or using the $regex in mongo...it never finds my data and appends it in the list.

EDIT: Adding in the full code along with what I am trying to identify:

```
RegEx = '.*\.com' #Or RegEx = re.compile('.*\.com')

def filterData(self, data):
       db = self.client[self.dbName]
       collection = db[self.collectionName]
       cursor = collection.find({'data.item11.sub.level3': {'$regex': RegEx}})
       data = []
       for x in cursor:
           data.append(x)
       return data
```

I am attempting to parse through JSON data in a mongodb. The data is structured like so:

```
"data": {
    "0": {
        "item1": "something",
        "item2": 0,
        "item3": 000,
        "item4": 000000000,
        "item5": 000000000,
        "item6": "0000",
        "item7": 00,
        "item8": "0000",
        "item9": 00,
        "item10": "useful",
        "item11": {
            "0000": {
                "sub": {
                    "level": "letter",
                    "level1": 0000,
                    "level2": 0000000000,
                    "level3": "domain.com"
                },
                "more_data": "words"
            }
        }
    }
```

UPDATE: After further testing it appears as though I need to include all of the layers in the search. Thus, it should look like

`collection.find({'data.0.item11.0000.sub.level3': {'$regex': RegEx}})`.

However, the "0" can be 1 - 50 and the "0000" is randomly generated. Is there a way to set these to index's as variables so that it will step into it no matter what the value? It will always be a number value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you need to tell mongodb the string should be treated as a regular expression, using the [`$regex`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) operator:

```
cursor = collection.find({'multiple.layers.of.data' : {'$regex': REGEX}})
```

I think simply replacing `REGEX = '.*\.com'` with `import re; REGEX = re.compile('.*\.com')` might also work, but I'm not sure (would rely on a specific handling in the `pymongo` driver).

---

EDIT:

Regarding the wildcard part of the question: The answer is no.

> In a nutshell, values that unknown should
>   never be assigned as keys because it makes querying very inefficient.
>   There are no 'wild card' queries.
>
> It is better to restructure the database such that values that are
>   unknown are not keys

See:

[MongoDB wildcard in the key of a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179871/mongodb-wildcard-in-the-key-of-a-query)

http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/32b00d38d50bd858

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/TnAQMe-5ZGs

Comment: Unfortunately, I have tried both of those methods and still run into the same problem. I can tell that the script is searching the data, but the matches are never appended to my list.

Comment: @user3413087 aren't you missing the '0' level? shouldn't it be 'data.0.item11....'?

Comment: Yes and no.... You can search through levels in mongodb and I've done it on some other sections. It could be that is the case and if so then I have another issue. The numbers at level "0" and "0000" are random. Also, the first one (0) increments by 1 each item that is returned under data and my data typically starts at 2 and can go to 20+. That is why I am trying to skip specifically identifying them. I've seen some documentation that shows skipping levels and assumed it would be okay.

Comment: You are correct in I need to list out the other layers. I tested it and it worked. That being said those two layers need to be a variable... Is there any way to do this?

Comment: thanks for the info. This is very unfortunate...I have no way to re-structure the data because I do not control it so I will need to find another way to tackle this. Thanks again.