# MongoDB Regex pattern or wildcard in query key

Tags: regex, mongodb, key, database

I must somehow set a wildcard in one of the keys in my mongodb query. So that `*.files.FileID` checks also the following keys of my document:
`root.files.FileID`
`root.folders.0.files.FileID`

My attempt was to simply do this: `db.user_folders.find({ '*.files.FileID' : 6 })`
But it returns no results.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179871/mongodb-wildcard-in-the-key-of-a-query

Comment: It is not possible. In `SQL` terms it would mean, `select col* from table where col*=6`; Does that query make any sense?  Rather it should have been `select col1,col2 from table where col1=6 OR col2=6`. Same logic applies here too.

Answer (score 0):

The only query operators acting on the fields of a document (as opposed to the value of those fields) are the `$exists` and `$type` operators.

There are basically two ways to go from here:

- Rework you documents' structure (it is hard to advise on this without intimate knowledge of your datasets and use cases), this is defintely the better choice on the long-term;
- Fetch all documents from the collection and query fields manually outside of MongoDB (this should only be used if you cannot modify the documents' structure or for a "just this once" corner case).