# How to query a value in a nested document without having the path?

Tags: mongodb

I have these documents stored in my mongoDB database.

```
{
  '_id' : 1,
  'field1' : {
               'cool_field1': 'value_1',
               'name' : 'good_name'
             }
  'field2' : {
               'cool_field1': 'value_2',
               'name' : 'bad_name'
             }
}
```

I'd like to query on `'name': 'good_name'` and I'd like to get `field1`. Since I do not know in which nested document `good_name` will be present, I can't use path query. I do not know if Mongo has a way of solving my problem or I will have to iterate over the full document in my native language once I retrieved the document.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you change the schema?

Comment: How many `fieldX` do you have?

Comment: The schema is not this one of course, but I can't change it since it answer to some other needs. I can have from one up to hundreds of fields. So I need a solution which find field1. However it might be important to know that I will have only once `good_name`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB wildcard in the key of a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179871/mongodb-wildcard-in-the-key-of-a-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongo wildcard query has been a long outstanding issue that you can track [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-267). Apparently no immediate out of the box solution to do this on the server.