# Does mongodb have a path wildcard?

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb collection where each document has a tree structure.  The first level is country code, the second is operating system, the third is processor type and finally the values are a performance score:

```
{ "AU": {"OSX":{"x86_64":17.4}},
  "RU": {"Android":{"A9":14.2,"x86":7.9},"iOS":{"A9":10.4}}
}
```

In a find query I can return just the Russian Android data like this:

```
db.scores.findOne({},{"RU.Android":1});
```

Is there a way of returning just the Android data, regardless of country?  Is there some wildcard that I can put into the selector?  Something like this:

```
db.scores.findOne({},{"*.Android":1});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB wildcard in the key of a query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179871/mongodb-wildcard-in-the-key-of-a-query)

Comment: Alas I think you are right.  Thanks for the link.  I searched but obviously not hard enough.

Comment: The best think to do is change  your documents structure so you can have uniform key. Perhaps something like `{'name':  'AU', 'sys': {"OSX": {"x86_64": 17.4}}}`

Comment: Unfortunately I would essentially have to turn this into SQL if I were to do that for each of the breakdowns I need and then performance goes downhill.  The locality of the data in the documents is good.  I'll just do the slicing once the data has come out.  This does the trick: <code>tree_math.find(findOne(),function(path,val){if(path[1]==="Android")tree_math.incrementPath(ans,path.slice(2),val)})</code>

Comment: You can issue an update query to do that.

Comment: The collection is a time series with one document per second.  I don't really want to change that, especially if that will mean exploding the number of documents.  Thanks for the suggestion but in this case I think postprocessing is the way to go.