# Select specific index field in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb

I want to select only the "thetext" field on a specific index for example when the `"comment_count"= 1`

I have tried this query:

`db.getCollection('mongotesi').find({},{'bug.long_desc.1.thetext':'1'})`

I want show all the "thetext" fields too.
This is the json structure:

```
    { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5613c8acc8e53ab811000083"), 
    "@attributes" : {
        "version" : "4.4.10", 
        "urlbase" : "https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/", 
        "maintainer" : "hostmaster@documentfoundation.org"
    }, 
    "bug" : {
        "bug_id" : "31585", 
        "creation_ts" : "2010-11-12 08:55:00 +0000", 
        "long_desc" : [
            {
                "@attributes" : {
                    "isprivate" : "0"
                }, 
                "commentid" : "194230", 
                "comment_count" : "0", 
                "attachid" : "40242", 
                "who" : "eric.moret", 
                "bug_when" : "2010-11-12 08:55:52 +0000", 
                "thetext" : "Created attachment 40242ooo base fileI am running ooo 3.2.1 OOO320m18 (Build:9502). I am using an odb bas file to perform a mail merge on an odt file under writer. In the mail merge Wizard, on hitting Next in step 6. (Edit Document), the Status window - creating document opens up and generates my mailing. The crash happens reliably while performing this task. I have 118 items to generate.My error report id is: rpmrd6nAttached are the 2 files used for this merge."
            }, 
            {
                "@attributes" : {
                    "isprivate" : "0"
                }, 
                "commentid" : "194232", 
                "comment_count" : "1", 
                "attachid" : "40243", 
                "who" : "eric.moret", 
                "bug_when" : "2010-11-12 08:56:29 +0000", 
                "thetext" : "Created attachment 40243ooo write file"
            },    
        ], 
    }
}
```

Comment: I asked something very similar yesterday and the answer is no, mongo doesn't support this yet.  I can get you references and tools if you like.

Comment: Here was my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32976362/does-mongodb-have-a-path-wildcard?noredirect=1#comment53778683_32976362  I use a node module "tree-math" to slice and dice the data when it comes out.  Disclaimer:  I wrote tree-math.  Promotion: tree-math is awesome.

Comment: not return exact key value but return specific position array using [slice](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/)

Comment: Whit $slice my result start always from the 0 position. If i want the n-position, how can i do with $slice? Could you help me writing a query? Thnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Arrays take the form of [ skip , limit ], where the first value indicates the number of items in the array to skip and the second value indicates the number of items to return.

Using [$slice](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) query will be for finding first array object

```
db.collection.find({},{"bug.long_desc":{"$slice":[0,1]},"@attributes":0})
```

if you find out second object then skip first object like this

```
db.collection.find({},{"bug.long_desc":{"$slice":[1,2]},"@attributes":0})
```

**EDIT**

If print exact matching text then use [forEach](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) as :

```
db.collection.find({},{"bug.long_desc":{"$slice":[0,1]},"@attributes":0}).forEach(function(doc){print(doc.bug.long_desc[0].thetext);})
```

Comment: ok, thanks a lot. Now if i want just the "thetext" print how can i do? `db.mongotesi.findOne({},{"bug.long_desc":{$slice:[0,1]}}).bug.long_desc` next ".bug.long_desc" what i have to add? –

Comment: @J.arc check edited answer to print exact matching key then use forEach to query

Answer (score 0):

Mongo doesn't do this but this will do the trick:

```
var tm = require('tree-math');
var long_desc=db.getCollection('mongotesi').find({},{'bug.long_desc':'1'});
var bugtext = {};
tm.find(long_desc,function(path,val {if(path[3]==='thetext')tm.setPath(bugtext,path,val);});
console.log(JSON.stringify(bugtext,null,2));
```

Comment: Thanks, but Im using R language, suggestions?