# How to use wildcard in field name in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I am a new learner for mongoDB. Now, I need to filter out documents where "N>0".
Due to "fieldX1", "fieldX2" and "fieldX3" have many different values, do we have any way to do something like: "fieldC.*.N": {$gt: 0} ?

```
fieldA: xxx
fieldB: xxx
fieldC: 
     fieldX1:
           N:2
     fieldX2:
           N:1
     fieldX3:
           N:3
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB wildcard in the key of a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179871/mongodb-wildcard-in-the-key-of-a-query)

Answer (score 0):

I think the only option here is to use the `$where` operator.

```
db.collection.find({
  "$where": "function() { for (var field in this.fieldC) { if (this.fieldC[field].N > 0) return true; } return false; }"
})
```

Make sure that the `$where` operator is enabled in your MongoDB configuration. Be aware that this can not be indexed.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2YvOMvpicb5)