# How to query mongodb wildcard sub fields in filter and projection?

Tags: mongodb

I have this structure of a document:

```json
{
  "1": {
    "type1": 1,
    "type2": 2
  },
  "2": {
    "type1": 11,
    "type2": 12
  }
}
// There can by multiple values at all levels, not just 2
```

Now I want to to query for all `type2` with a filter, conceptually:

```
"*.type2" > 10
```

And I want to return only one field as well, so that the result would look like that:

```json
{
  "10": {
    "type2": 20
  },
  "20": {
    "type2": 25
  }
}
```

Is it possible to achieve in MongoDB with a single query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB wildcard in the key of a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179871/mongodb-wildcard-in-the-key-of-a-query)

Comment: Thanks for the link, it does not quite do it unfortunately, but the provided answer seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to iterate over the keys and keep only the `type2` with value greater than 10.
In order to iterate over the keys we are using `$objectToArray`. In order to keep only the `type2`, we use `$reduce` to iterate (which allow to format the item), instead of a simple `$filter` that will just return the un-formatted matching items. The last step is just to format back the array to a dictionary.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {
      _id: 0,
      data: {$reduce: {
          input: {$objectToArray: "$$ROOT"},
          initialValue: [],
          in: {$concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              {$cond: [
                  {$gt: ["$$this.v.type2", 10]},
                  [{k: "$$this.k", v: {type2: "$$this.v.type2"}}],
                  []
              ]}
          ]}
      }}
  }},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: {$arrayToObject: "$data"}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nZYWMi-ys0_)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I cannot say I fully understand what is going on in here but it works :) I am wondering if the performance/load on the mongodb server would be huge for operations of these type compared to just returning the whole document and doing it on the client

Comment: Would it also be possible to just project to get "type2" for all without a query? It can be done with your query by removing $cond, but maybe there is some simpler way for such a projection?

Comment: Not a simple way that I know-of with this dynamic path to `type2`, not without `$objectToArray`