# how to search different objects in array mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to mongo database
and this is my first question in stack overflow,

and I have collection with a document like this :

```
{
   "id" : 1,
   "language" :[
     {"English" :"hello"},
     {"French" : "bonjour"}
   ]
}
```

I cant find  a query to search all values of language ( hello , bonjour) .. whatever this object property name
thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB wildcard in the key of a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179871/mongodb-wildcard-in-the-key-of-a-query)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the [aggregation framework](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/aggregation/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      expressions: {
        $let: {
          vars: {
            languageKV: {
              $map: {
                input: "$language",
                as: "lang",
                in: { $arrayElemAt: [{ $objectToArray: "$$lang" }, 0] },
              },
            },
          },
          in: {
            $map: {
              input: "$$languageKV",
              as: "lang",
              in: "$$lang.v",
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
])
```

with this code a new array (`expressions`) is added for each record containing only the keys of your objects on which you can search with [$match](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) operator.

PS: I don't know if this is the best performing solution