# MongoDB Find Id in Array without knowing nested object path

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongodb-query

**QUESTION**

I need to query data that is stored in mongo and find a particular id within an array without knowing the name of the sub key. In my example below, I am trying to find "AA" within the nested object "active.????" without knowing all the possible sub keys. Does mongodb have a wildcard option or is there another way to query the key?

**DATA**

```json
[{
  "_id": "1",
  "active":{
    "a": [1,2,'a','c'],
    "b": [3,'d','AA'],
    "c": [4,5,6,7,'f','g','h'],
    "d": ['AA'],
  },
  "inactive":{
    "a": ['z','BB'],
  },
},{
  "_id": "2",
  "active":{
    "j": ['AA'],
  },
  "inactive":{}
},{
  "_id": "3",
  "active":{
    "d": ['k'],
  },
  "inactive":{}
}]
```

**QUERY**

```bash
db.col.find({"active.*":"AA"})
```

**Expected Result**

```json
[ { _id: "1" }, { _id: "2" } ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB wildcard in the key of a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179871/mongodb-wildcard-in-the-key-of-a-query)