# How to search in all object keys?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

Given multiples documents containing a key named `userId`, where this key is **always** an object:

```js
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "22fc6b11a0ff111d598b114f"
        },
        "userId": {
            "KEY1"  : ["..."],
            "KEY2"  : ["..."],
            "KEY3"  : ["..."],
            "KEY4"  : ["..."]
        },
    }
```

It will always contain 4 sub-keys, where each of these is always a non-empty array of **strings**

How I can search over all documents looking inside each of these KEY's?

For example:

```js
    /* MONGO document

    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "65fc6b08a0ffe6dd598b114f"
        },
        "userId": {
            "KEY1"  : ["1", "2", "3"],
            "KEY2"  : ["A", "Z"]
            ...
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "22fc6b11a0ff111d598b114f"
        },
        "userId": {
            "KEY1"  : ["4", "5", "6"],
            "KEY2"  : ["Z", "X"]
            ...
        },
    }
    */

    const array = ["2", "X"];
    const users = await db.collection("users").find({ "userId": { "$in": array } }).toArray();
    console.log(users)
```

`const array = ["2", "X"];` <- I'm trying to specify an array of strings and find all documents
that contains any of these strings in any of the sub-keys arrays of the `userId` object

In this case, it would match both documents, because `2` exists on the first document `userId.KEY1`
and `X` exists on the second document `userId.KEY2`

`const array = ["X"];` This would match just the second document

My attempt is not finding any match, how i could achieve this?

Comment: You should be able to use Mongo's `$objectToArray` to transform the userId into an array that can be deconstructed and filtered.
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB wildcard in the key of a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179871/mongodb-wildcard-in-the-key-of-a-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`$setIntersection`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) of the input `array` with the [`$setUnion`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) of the values of KEY's. Note however that this requires mongo to construct the Union before doing the intersection check which may not be very optimal and won't use any indexes.

```js
db.collection.find({
  $expr: { $ne: [
    {
      $setIntersection: [
        ["2", "X"],
        { $setUnion: ["$userId.KEY1", "$userId.KEY2", "$userId.KEY3", "$userId.KEY4"] }
      ]
    },
    []]
  }
})
```

[Mongo Plaground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lkjFbmiKcaj)

And if you have *many* KEY's, it fits well with [jQueeny's answer of constructing a string of $KEY's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78208775/1431750) to use in the `setUnion` part.

If you did have an arbitrary number of KEYs - and not always the exact same 4 - you can also use [`$objectToArray`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) as [suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78207168/how-to-search-in-all-object-keys#comment137876701_78207168):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $set: { allKEYs: { $objectToArray: "$userId" } } },
  { $match: { "allKEYs.v": { $in: ["2", "X" ] } } },
  { $unset: "allKEYs" }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bemFSf5Awu9)

Also won't use any index so I'd recommend jQueeny's answer over this for your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `$or` in your `find()` query like so:

```js
const array = ["2", "X"];
const users = await db.collection("users").find({
  $or: [
    {
      "userId.KEY1": {
        $in: array
      }
    },
    {
      "userId.KEY2": {
        $in: array
      }
    },
    {
      "userId.KEY3": {
        $in: array
      }
    },
    {
      "userId.KEY4": {
        $in: array
      }
    }
  ]
}).toArray();
```

See [HERE](https://mongoplayground.net/p/c9pDeh3klh2) for a working example.

If you have a long list of `KEYn` keys for example `KEY1`, `KEY2`...`KEY99` then you can construct your query object `$or` array using a simple for loop like so:

```js
const array = ["2", "X"];
const orArray = [];
const numKeys = 100; // range from KEY1...KEY99
for(i=1; i < numKeys; i++){
  orArray.push(
    {
      [`"userId.KEY${i}"`]: {
        "$in": array
      }
    }
  );
}
const users = await db.collection("users").find({
  $or: orArray
}).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

To archive your goal, you need to use the MongoDB aggregation framework with `$or` operator and `$eleMatch` to search within array of objects.

```
const array = ["2", "X"];

const user = await db.collection("users").aggregate([
{
$match:{
$or: {
{ "userId.KEY1": { $elemMatch: { $in: array } } },
{ "userId.KEY2": { $elemMatch: { $in: array } } },
{ "userId.KEY3": { $elemMatch: { $in: array } } },
}
}
}
]).toArray();
console.log(users);
```

This query will match documents where any of the userId sub-keys contain at least one element that is present in the array